# Layout of list with different elements type in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to fix a list with elements that have different types. Each of the type has it's own datatype to represent the viewmodel for each type. The following code works for me, but for some reason the data inside gets truncated, to some value (looks like default). I need to remove this trancation.

Here is what I have. This code is in the control, that could be placed in a list as well (it could be doubled or tripled). But I Don't think it's relevant.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ListView DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="testCaseResultListView" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding LogItems}" 
                      ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource fixSideViewLogItemStyleSelector}"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="gridView2">
                    <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Style>
                    </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource fixSideViewLogItemTemplateSelector}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

`fixSideViewLogItemTemplateSelector` and `fixSideViewLogItemStyleSelector` are the selectors, that return different datatypes or styles for each of the type in `LogItems`. The common datatype is a grid with two columns, but that also seems irrelevent - I tried to put a textbox there, and it still gets truncated.[image: Example of what I get]

I would like this column to be stretched to the whole gridView. When I set width, of the column, I see the column resizing, but I want it to occupy the whole space. This should be elastic - if I put one control in the window, it should occupy the whole window, and properly resize (with it's column) when the window is resized. If I put two controls, they should divide the space by halves, and still should be resized when the window is resized.

Any help, tips?

**Upd**
Here is an example of the template I'm using.

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="testCaseDataResultTemplate">
        <!-- Test case results -->
        <Grid Margin="50,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                <!--Test case result property-->
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <!--Is retry / Name-->
                <RowDefinition />
                <!--Test case number-->
                <RowDefinition />
                <!--Low limit-->
                <RowDefinition />
                <!--High limit-->
                <RowDefinition />
                <!--Measured-->
                <RowDefinition />
                <!--State-->
                <RowDefinition />
                <!--Test time-->
                <RowDefinition />
                <!--Comment-->
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--Is retry / Name-->
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                               Source="..\Resources\retry16.png" 
                               Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                               Visibility="{Binding Path=IsRetry, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <TextBlock Text="fh fhgfhg fhfhfhgfhg fhgfhfhgfhgfhgfhgfhgfhgf hgfhgfhgfhgfhgfhg fhfhgfhgf hgfhgfhfhg fhfhgf rdederserswerv 2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"/>
            <!--Test case number-->
            <TextBlock Text="Number:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TestCaseNumber}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
            <!--Low limit-->
            <TextBlock Text="Low limit:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TestCaseData.LimitData.LowLimit}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
            <!--High limit-->
            <TextBlock Text="High limit: " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TestCaseData.LimitData.HighLimit}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" />
            <!--Measured-->
            <TextBlock Text="Measured" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MeasuredValue, Converter={StaticResource valasaConverter}}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" />
            <!--State-->
            <TextBlock Text="Passed: " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Passed}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" />
            <!--Test time-->
            <TextBlock Text="Test time: " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TestTime, StringFormat={}{0:hh':'mm':'ss'.'ff}}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" />
            <!--Comment-->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ShortMessage}" 
                                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                   Visibility="{Binding Path=HasComment, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityColConverter}}" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                   MaxWidth="400" 
                                   TextAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FullMessage}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

It's a bit messy, but it is very simple. It has two columns - the captions, and the values. These columns are nothing to do with truncation.

I have tried also this template:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="testCaseDataResultTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="Long long text goes here...... ->" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

The text was of course longer :) It was still truncating, so I blame the listView/GridView, but not the inner template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot say that I solved the puzzle, but at least it works as I expected. I removed the whole definition with GridView and columns inside, and put ItemTemplateSelector directly in ListView.

So my ListView looks now like this:

```
            <ListView DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="testCaseResultListView" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding LogItems}" 
                      ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource fixSideViewLogItemStyleSelector}"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource fixSideViewLogItemTemplateSelector}">
```

That did it! Hope that will help to somebody as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this issue maybe is that you need to set the `ListView.HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`. Also the item container style and the item template must have the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch` and the `Width` property must be `Auto`. Hope this tips helps...

**EDIT**

---

Also I think the problem could be the width of the `GridViewColumn`, that fix the items width
to it's own width. If you are using a single column, maybe you can change the `ListView` to a `ListBox` or an `ItemsControl`, just an idea.

Comment: Tried to put both HorizontalContentAlignment and HorizontalAlighnemnt as a Stretch for all the tags, starting from ListView and down to text box. The same with Width. Still nothing

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your templates looks like but I see a problem like this, it normally lies with a TextBlock that isn't wrapping and/or that the TextBlock's width is longer than it's parent.